# How do the internals of the cron daemon work?

Tags: cron

I want to know how `cron` works internally. Does the process keep checking the current time in an infinite while loop (thus continually consuming CPU cycles)? Or does some function generate an interrupt and notifies the `cron` daemon ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I once read the vixie-cron source code and had to be hospitalized. However if you're looking for "some function generate an interrupt" at a time in the future, you should investigate the `alarm(2)` syscall. It asks the kernel to send you the signal `SIGALRM` at a scheduled time, which you can then catch. In the mean time, your process can do something else, or `sleep()`, like I did in the hospital.

Comment: Upvoted for humor.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure there are many variations, the way it works in *dcron* (aka Dillon's cron daemon) is that it sleeps for up to 60 seconds at a time, it tries to synchronise this by sleeping less if needed so as to wake up at 00 seconds of each minute.

It uses `sleep()` which puts the process to sleep (unless a signal occurs) without using CPU.
When it wakes, it checks for a file `cron.update` (created by `crontab` editing). It recreates its run queue if required, runs the expected tasks, and sleeps again.

At least one cron daemon (`fcrond`) uses a signal sent by crontab editing to the cron daemon instead of a sleep/check approach.

I've never seen a crond that runs things more frequently than once per-minute, so they are usually quite light on resources.

On Linux, if you look in `/proc` at things like bytes read/written or iowait for `crond` you may see that it has relatively high usage, this is because it ends up accounting for all the child processes that it starts, e.g. on CentOS 5.x:

```
# grep "^[rw]" /proc/`pgrep crond`/io
rchar: 153463658151
wchar: 91095820045
read_bytes: 44480745472
write_bytes: 2261389312
```

(thanks to scheduled package updates, and ASLR/pre-link tasks in this case)

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982957/how-does-cron-internally-schedule-jobs .

Comment: At least one exception exists: [`fcron`](http://fcron.free.fr/) does not wake up each minute just to check whether it has something to do. “Then, fcron calculates the time and date of each job's next execution, and determines how long it has to sleep, and sleeps for this amount of time.” – man fcron

Comment: Nice one, not familiar with `fcrond`, just checked the source: it invokes a helper to HUP the `crond`.